# I cannot connect other container in overlay network when cross machines

Tags: docker

I created 3 VM CentOS-7 on my Windows10. All of them were installed Docker and closed firewalld.

But I cannot connect the other machine's container over **overlay** network. **Did I do something wrong?**

Here are my settins:

#### **192.168.153.131**

- install Consul
- export 8500 port
- In Consul, I can see the next 2 nodes : 192.168.153.132 and 192.168.153.133.

#### **192.168.153.132**

- set `--cluster-store=consul://192.168.153.131:8500/network`

  - `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --cluster-advertise=ens33:2375 --cluster-store=consul://192.168.153.131:8500/network`
- create overlay network successfully

  - `docker network create -d overlay alice`
- run 3 nginx container in the network **alice**(`--network alice`), the IP of them are`10.0.0.2`, `10.0.0.3` and `10.0.0.4`

#### **192.168.153.133**

- set `--cluster-store=consul://192.168.153.131:8500/network`
- can find network **alice** successfully
- run 1 nginx container in the network **alice**(IP:`10.0.0.5`)
- run 1 debian container in the network **alice**(IP:`10.0.0.6`)

  - In this container, I can receive response from `10.0.0.5`, but **cannot** receive reponse from `10.0.0.3`

```
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
...
```

Could you help me, please. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that, to use overlay network, I also have to do these:

- set unique hostname for each machine `hostname ser2`
- set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- set network `ifconfig ens33 promisc`
- add argument `--attachable` when create overlay network, like`docker network create -d overlay --attachable alice`

And then the overlay network can work. Very good.